# Timestamps of Odometry and IMU

Tags: ros, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> [ERROR] [1323209887.229712458]:
> Timestamps of odometry and imu are
> 1.490433 seconds apart.

Can anyone explain the above error message? Is there a suggested fix?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12242/timestamps-of-odometry-and-imu/) by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-12-07**:
This is being published when minimal is launched.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-07**:
What is throwing this error? What is publishing odometry and imu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means that the messages coming from the imu and the odometry have timestamps that are very different. This can be caused by messages getting delayed because of high system load, or by clocks of different hosts that are not synchronized. In any case, you cannot expect your system to run properly with such high difference in timestamps.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-03-24**:
I have the same problem with robot_pose_ekf. Did you fix it??